# Java - reduce code duplication - General coding question

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm looking for a way to reduce duplication in my code.

I have these 2 classes with same methods and **ONLY** difference `private final House number;` and `private final NewHouse number;`  :

```
public class Building {

    private final UUID id;
    private final House number;
    private final HouseType houseType;

    Building(UUID Id, House number, HouseType houseType) {
        this.id = id;
        //....//
    }

    public House getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    //get/set
    //other methods

}

public class NewBuilding {

    private final UUID id;
    private final NewHouse number;
    private final HouseType houseType;

    NewBuilding(UUID id, NewHouse number, HouseType houseType) {
        this.id = id;
        //....//
    }

    public NewHouse getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    //get/set
    //other methods
}
```

Is there some way that I can combine this two classes in one and reduce duplication in my code?

Is there some design pattern that I can use? Should I create some 3rd class with common functionality?

Comment: This question should be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ not here. Please consider posting there.

Comment: Secondly, what is the difference between your House and NewHouse class?

Answer (score 2):

YES.

You can create single class with [Generic Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) + [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) extend new classes.

Let's say:

```
public class Structure<T> {

    private final UUID id;
    private final T number;
    private final HouseType houseType;

    Structure(UUID Id, T number, HouseType houseType) {
        this.id = id;
        //....//
    }

    public T getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    //get/set
    //other methods
}
```

Your `House` class:

```
public class Building extends Structure<House> {

    //number attribute instanceof House 
    //get/set
    //other methods
}
```

Your `NewHouse` class:

```
public class NewBuilding extends Structure<NewHouse> {

    //number attribute instanceof NewHouse 
    //get/set
    //other methods

}
```

Comment: Surely it's just a typo, but the constructor of Structure should be `Structure`, not `Building`

Comment: Thanks. Copy + paste issue :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just use parametrized types

```
public class Building<T> {

private final UUID id;
private final T number;
private final HouseType houseType;

Building(UUID Id, T number, HouseType houseType) {
    this.id = Id;
    this.number = number;
    this.houseType = houseType;
}

public T getNumber() {
    return number;
}

//get/set
//other methods
```

}

So you can use the following syntax

```
 Building<House> building = new Building<>(UUID.randomUUID(), new House(), new HouseType());
 Building<NewHouse> newHouse = new Building<>(UUID.randomUUID(), new NewHouse(), new HouseType());
```

Comment: Also, if `House` and `NewHouse` share a common ancestor or interface (let's say `IHouse`), you'd better use `Building<T extends IHouse>` to restrict the accepted types.

Answer (score 0):

Create third class which will be a parent to the 2 existing siblings:

```
public class GenericBuilding {
  private final UUID id;
  private final HouseType houseType;
  //...
}

public class Building extends GenericBuilding {
  private final House number;
  //...
}

public class NewBuilding extends GenericBuilding {
  private final NewHouse number;
  //...
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can create an Abstract class (say Construction) containing all the common variables and methods.
Then have the two class Building and NewBuilding extend the Abstract class(Construction)

[Link explaining abstraction](https://javatutorial.net/java-abstraction-example)

Comment: If you create abstract class and exclude the House and NewHouse which are not common, what will rest of the functions do without these important variables? Your abstract class would have no implementation which would make it just like an interface. And even in that scenario code will be duplicated.